# Will tuning old Bongos break the drum heads?

Tags: tuning, maintenance, bongos

I have a set of old LP Aspire Bongos that I got from my father. They are probably 15 years old or so, and it's unlikely that they have ever been tuned, definitely not for last 12 years.

I'd like to tune them so they don't sound flat, but I'm worried about the drum heads. They feel dry and "set" around the edges. I'm not in a position where I can easily replace the heads, so I'd rather have flat drums than unplayable drums. If I try to tune them, thus pulling on this 12-15 year crease they have gotten used to, will they break?